# Error writing CodeIgniter incorrect forms to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email, phpmyadmin

I've added a contact form and I've added a captcha validation, the contact form is working.

but even the faulty forms write to the database. Even if you press the submit button without filling the error form at all, it is registered in the database.

How do I get only successful jerseys to register in the database

this is my controller codes

```
public function contact(){

    $viewData = new stdClass();
    $viewData->viewFolder = "contact_v";
    $this->load->helper("captcha");

    $config = array(
        "word"          => '',
        "img_path"      => 'captcha/',
        "img_url"       => base_url("captcha"),
        "font_path"     => 'base_url("fonts/corbel.ttf")',
        "img_width"     => 150,
        "img_height"    => 50,
        "expiration"    => 7200,
        "word_length"   => 4,
        "font_size"     => 40,
        "img_id"        => "captcha_img",
        "pool"          => "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        "colors"        => array(
            'background' => array(0,0,0),
            'border'     => array(0,0,0),
            'text'       => array(255,255,255),
            'grid'       => array(0,0,0),
        )

    );

    $viewData->captcha = create_captcha($config);

    $this->session->set_userdata("captcha", $viewData->captcha["word"]);

    $this->load->view($viewData->viewFolder, $viewData);


}  


public function send_contact_message(){


    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->model("Contact_model");

        $insert = $this->Contact_model->add(
            array(
                "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
                "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
                "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
                "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
                "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            )
        );


    $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Ad", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "E-posta", "trim|required|valid_email");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subject", "Konu", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Mesaj", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("captcha", "Doğrulama Kodu", "trim|required");
    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){

        // TODO Alert...
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Action Completed');
        redirect(base_url("iletisim"));


    } else {


        if($this->session->userdata("captcha") == $this->input->post("captcha")){

            $name = $this->input->post("name");
            $email = $this->input->post("email");
            $subject = $this->input->post("subject");
            $message = $this->input->post("message");

            $email_message = "{$name} isimli ziyaretçi. Mesaj Bıraktı <br><b>Mesaj : </b> {$message} <br> <b>E-posta : </b> {$email}";

            if(send_email("", "Site başvuru Mesajı | $subject", $email_message)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("iletisim"));
                // TODO Alert..
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("iletisim"));
                // TODO Alert..
            }

        } else {
            //başarısıs
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
        redirect(base_url("iletisim"));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through it and found that you are inserting the data first and then performing validation which is not at all correct.

You should write your function in the following way,

```
public function contact(){

    $viewData = new stdClass();
    $viewData->viewFolder = "contact_v";
    $this->load->helper("captcha");

    $config = array(
        "word"          => '',
        "img_path"      => 'captcha/',
        "img_url"       => base_url("captcha"),
        "font_path"     => 'base_url("fonts/corbel.ttf")',
        "img_width"     => 150,
        "img_height"    => 50,
        "expiration"    => 7200,
        "word_length"   => 4,
        "font_size"     => 40,
        "img_id"        => "captcha_img",
        "pool"          => "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        "colors"        => array(
                            'background' => array(0,0,0),
                            'border'     => array(0,0,0),
                            'text'       => array(255,255,255),
                            'grid'       => array(0,0,0),
        )
    );

    $viewData->captcha = create_captcha($config);
    $this->session->set_userdata("captcha", $viewData->captcha["word"]);
    $this->load->view($viewData->viewFolder, $viewData);
}  


public function send_contact_message(){

    $this->load->library("form_validation");
    $this->load->model("Contact_model");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "Ad", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", "E-posta", "trim|required|valid_email");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subject", "Konu", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("message", "Mesaj", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("captcha", "Doğrulama Kodu", "trim|required");
    if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        // TODO Alert...
        $this->session->set_flashdata('info','Action Completed');
        redirect(base_url("iletisim"));
    } else {

        $insert = $this->Contact_model->add(
            array(
                "name"          => $this->input->post("name"),
                "email"         => $this->input->post("email"),
                "message"       => $this->input->post("message"),
                "subject"       => $this->input->post("subject"),
                "created_at"    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            )
        );

        if($this->session->userdata("captcha") == $this->input->post("captcha")){

            $name = $this->input->post("name");
            $email = $this->input->post("email");
            $subject = $this->input->post("subject");
            $message = $this->input->post("message");

            $email_message = "{$name} isimli ziyaretçi. Mesaj Bıraktı <br><b>Mesaj : </b> {$message} <br> <b>E-posta : </b> {$email}";

            if(send_email("", "Site başvuru Mesajı | $subject", $email_message)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("iletisim"));
                // TODO Alert..
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Action Completed');
                redirect(base_url("iletisim"));
                // TODO Alert..
            }

        } else {
            //başarısıs
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Action Not Completed');
        redirect(base_url("iletisim"));

        }
    }
}
```

This will prevent you from inserting wrong data. If validation fails then it will redirect you on the page which you have written inside "if" block of second function

Comment: Thank you very much.
I am new to this forum and I am very happy that my problem is solved.

Comment: Your welcome, I would like if  you approve my answer, Thank you